# How can I use factor level with known date format to inform the rest of my dataframe?

Tags: r, date, time

I have GPS data for multiple individuals but the dates are inconsistent. For instance, some are in `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"` format but others are in `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"`format. This is very confusing but I know the correct order of one of the individuals.

Can I use this to inform the date transformation `parse_date_time` from the `lubridate` package? Or what is the best way around this ambiguity?

```
date, id,
"10/01/2014 08:00", A # these are day/month/year format
"10/01/2014 06:00", A
"09/01/2014 18:00", A
"09/01/2014 15:00", A
"09/01/2014 12:00", A
"09/01/2014 10:00", A
"10/01/2014 10:00", B # these are month/day/year format
"10/01/2014 10:00", B
"10/01/2014 10:00", B
"10/01/2014 10:00", B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` functions `mutate` and `case_when` to use the `id` column to apply the `dmy_hm` or `mdy_hm` function accordingly.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble) # for tribble
library(lubridate)

df <- tribble(~date, ~id,
"10/01/2014 08:00", "A", # these are day/month/year format
"10/01/2014 06:00", "A",
"09/01/2014 18:00", "A",
"09/01/2014 15:00", "A",
"09/01/2014 12:00", "A",
"09/01/2014 10:00", "A",
"10/01/2014 10:00", "B", # these are month/day/year format
"10/01/2014 10:00", "B",
"10/01/2014 10:00", "B",
"10/01/2014 10:00", "B")

mutate(df, date = case_when(id == "A" ~ dmy_hm(date),
                        id == "B" ~ mdy_hm(date)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    date                id   
#>    <dttm>              <chr>
#>  1 2014-01-10 08:00:00 A    
#>  2 2014-01-10 06:00:00 A    
#>  3 2014-01-09 18:00:00 A    
#>  4 2014-01-09 15:00:00 A    
#>  5 2014-01-09 12:00:00 A    
#>  6 2014-01-09 10:00:00 A    
#>  7 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B    
#>  8 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B    
#>  9 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B    
#> 10 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Great! And what is the syntax for multiple conditions? `id== "A"  | id =="C"`

Comment: Correct.  `case_when` can also include a "not matched" by specifying `TRUE ~ 'whatever'`

Comment: I tried to solve this question. Was almsot done but date keeps returning funny digits and couldn't figure out how to go about it. Returns things like:  1389340800    for the first row, what could be wrong? Was using `ifelse` if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

After a few trials, I learnt that `ifelse` from base coerces to double. `if_else` however helps solve the problem:

```
   library(tidyverse)
      df %>% 
  mutate(id=as.factor(id),
         date=if_else(id=="A",dmy_hm(date),mdy_hm(date)))
```

Result:

```
 date                id   
   <dttm>              <fct>
 1 2014-01-10 08:00:00 A    
 2 2014-01-10 06:00:00 A    
 3 2014-01-09 18:00:00 A    
 4 2014-01-09 15:00:00 A    
 5 2014-01-09 12:00:00 A    
 6 2014-01-09 10:00:00 A    
 7 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B    
 8 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B    
 9 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B    
10 2014-10-01 10:00:00 B
```